# What is the difference between Enhancement Potential and Attack stats?

Tags: dragon-nest

I have this +7 Orc Axe that has Attack Power of 43-91 and Magic Power of 43-90. But the Enhancement Potential states that Attack Power is 61-128 Magic of 49-102.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially one number is how much stats your enhancement gives you, the other one is how much stats your weapon has without any enhancement.

Both numbers are added together into your total attack at the end of the day. They just allow you to see the difference between your weapon with them and without them.